# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an apllication using spring boot 2.7.1,  when i type the address http://localhost:9096/popup/111111, I get the below response:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
> /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Aug 02 12:20:32 CET 2022 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404).

[image]

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9096

spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    enabled: true
    mode: HTML5
    prefix: /templates/
    suffix: .html
```

controller:

```
@Controller("popup")
public class PopupRequest {

    @GetMapping("/{requestNumber}")
    String index(@PathVariable("requestNumber") String requestNumber) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding @RequestMapping("/popup") as an annotation to the class like so:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/popup")
public class PopupRequest {

    @GetMapping("/{requestNumber}")
    String index(@PathVariable("requestNumber") String requestNumber) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inclose request mapping with
parenthesis ("/")

```
    Controller
    @RequestMapping("/popup")
    public class PopupRequest {
    @GetMapping("/{requestNumber}")
 String index(@PathVariable("requestNumber")String r requestNumber){
    return "index";
      }
   }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).